# Object referencing in Java null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a object which contains an array of doubles.

```
public class NumberRow {

static final int MAX_AMOUNT_OF_NUMBERS = 2500;
double[] NumberArray = new double[MAX_AMOUNT_OF_NUMBERS];

NumberRow(double[] NumberArray){
    this.NumberArray = NumberArray;
}

}
```

In my main program I start with creating a array of the object NumberRow in the constructor like this

```
NumberRow[] numberRow;
```

later in the program I put this code:

```
numberRow = new NumberRow[dataset.numberOfVariables];
```

After that I call a function which gives value to an numberRow:

```
double misc = in.nextDouble();
numberRow[k].NumberArray[i] = misc;
```

I did say where NumberRow is pointing to. However, eclipse gives me a null pointer pointer exception on this line:

```
numberRow[k].NumberArray[i] = misc;
```

I hope anyone can see what I did wrong?
Thank you :)!

Comment: dataset.numberOfVariables == 0?

Comment: These little individual bits of code are very confusing.  Please construct a simple, but complete, test-case.

Comment: `double[] NumberArray = new double[MAX_AMOUNT_OF_NUMBERS];` is never used because you reallocate it in the constructor: `this.NumberArray = NumberArray;`. Are you sure that is what you intended?

Comment: `NumberRow[] numberRow;` isn't a constructor.  It doesn't "create" anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake I see when beginners start to use arrays of objects. When an array of object references is created, the array is initialized, but the individual elements in the array are `null`. So, on the statement `numberRow[k].NumberArray[i] = misc;`, `numberRow[k]` is `null`, which is causing the exception. Therefore, before the line, you need to put the statement

```
numberRow[k] = new NumberRow();
```

before the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

`numberRow = new NumberRow[dataset.numberOfVariables];`

All of the members of the array `numberRow` are initialized to the default value of `NumberRow`. `NumberRow` is a class, therefore its default value is null. To set values on something that is null, you must first initialize it to a `new`, real object or you will get a NullPointerException.